# Is there a simpler method for handling MULTIPLE references in OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, whiteboard

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
@References(
        value={
                @Reference(name="dataSources",cardinality=ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE,policy=ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,strategy=ReferenceStrategy.EVENT,bind="bind",unbind="unbind",referenceInterface=DataSourceProvider.class)
        })      
public class DataSourceStoreServiceImpl implements DataSourceStoreService {

    List<DataSourceProvider> dataSourceProviders = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<DataSourceProvider>();

    public void bind(DataSourceProvider dataSourceProvider) {
        dataSourceProviders.add(dataSourceProvider);
    }

    public void unbind(DataSourceProvider dataSourceProvider) {
        dataSourceProviders.remove(dataSourceProvider);
    }

}
```

This is how I handle refereces with `MULTIPLE` cardinality.

My question is whether it is possible to do it without the boilerplate? What I have in mind is something like this:

```
public class DataSourceStoreServiceImpl implements DataSourceStoreService {

    @CollectionType(CopyOnWriteArrayList.class)
    @Reference(name="dataSources",cardinality=ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE,policy=ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,strategy=ReferenceStrategy.EVENT,bind="bind",unbind="unbind",referenceInterface=DataSourceProvider.class)
    List<DataSourceProvider> dataSourceProviders

}
```

Comment: If you are using felix, have you tried iPOJO as this is designed to make these issues much simpler to deal with.

Comment: Not yet, but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: You should find iPOJO *much* simpler to use. (or at least that is it's purpose AFAIK)  I have used it in a number of projects, but never tried to use Felix by itself.

Comment: I'm actually using Karaf (which uses Felix). Does it work with Karaf?

Comment: I have only used iPOJO and Karaf, actually. ;)  They work together very well. IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [IPojo annotations](http://felix.apache.org/site/how-to-use-ipojo-annotations.html#HowtouseiPOJOAnnotations-@Updated).

Simply declaring an array with the annotation "requires" as in this example:

```
@Requires
private Hello[] m_hello; // Service Dependency
```

Then you can call your services like that:

```
for(Hello helloService: m_hello){
       helloService.ohHai("Test");
}
```

Oh I forgot, your provider class needs 2 annotations: `@Component` and `@Provides`
and your consumer class needs `@Component` and `@Instantiate`